# How to get PICC serial number on Arduino

Tags: arduino

how do i got about getting the serial number from a PICC tag?

Im currently using a RFID-RC522 card with an Arduino Uno, with its library that can be found [here](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/).. so hope this helps... here's my software and pin layout.. You can see that i tried to load the serial into a string, but to no avail:

```
/*
 * MFRC522 - Library to use ARDUINO RFID MODULE KIT 13.56 MHZ WITH TAGS SPI W AND R BY      COOQROBOT.
 * The library file MFRC522.h has a wealth of useful info. Please read it.
 * The functions are documented in MFRC522.cpp.
 *
 * Based on code Dr.Leong   ( WWW.B2CQSHOP.COM )
 * Created by Miguel Balboa (circuitito.com), Jan, 2012.
 * Rewritten by Søren Thing Andersen (access.thing.dk), fall of 2013 (Translation to      English, refactored, comments, anti collision, cascade levels.)
 * Released into the public domain.
 * Sample program showing how to read data from a PICC using a MFRC522 reader on the      Arduino SPI interface.
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------- empty_skull 
 * Aggiunti pin per arduino Mega
 * add pin configuration for arduino mega
 * http://mac86project.altervista.org/
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- Nicola      Coppola
 * Pin layout should be as follows:
 * Signal     Pin              Pin               Pin
 *            Arduino Uno      Arduino Mega      MFRC522 board
 * ------------------------------------------------------------
 * Reset      9                5                 RST
 * SPI SS     10               53                SDA
 * SPI MOSI   11               52                MOSI
 * SPI MISO   12               51                MISO
 * SPI SCK    13               50                SCK
 *
 * The reader can be found on eBay for around 5 dollars. Search for "mf-rc522" on    ebay.com. 
 */

 #include <SPI.h>
 #include <MFRC522.h>


 #define SS_PIN 10
 #define RST_PIN 9
 MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance.

 void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card
Serial.println("Scan PICC to see UID and type...");
 }

 void loop() {
// Look for new cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return;
}

// Select one of the cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return;
}

// Dump debug info about the card. PICC_HaltA() is automatically called.
//mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));

    String data = mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));

    if (data.substring(0) == "43 6F F6 A4") {
      
      Serial.print("Welcome Adam");
   } else {
      Serial.print("Invalid card, please try again"); 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String rfidUid = "";

for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
  rfidUid += String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
  rfidUid += String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
}

Serial.println(rfidUid);

if (rfidUid == "436ff6a4") {
  ...
```

Variable **rfidUid** will contain the UID as one string with lower case letters and no space.

Example: *5c022e31*

If the format must be with uppercase letters and spaces you might have success using **sprintf** instead.

Answer (score 1):

The above method only works if you are reading once, otherwise the uid's stack up for every read.  I tried this method and it did what I wanted, read the uid into array

```
data[i]=mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
```

then convert to string

```
code=String(data[0],HEX)+...+String(data[i],HEX); 
code.toUpperCase();Serial.println(code);
```